# Pandas conditional update dataframe value

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
    col1    col2    col3    col4
1     1      20      AA      NaN
2     2      10      BB      NaN
3     3      20      CC      NaN
4     1      30      AA      NaN
5     2      10      BB      NaN
```

I need to update col4 such that:

```
if col3 == 'AA':
    return col2 + col1
elif col2 == 'BB':
    return col2 - col1
else:
    return
```

So the output will look something like this:

```
    col1    col2    col3    col4
1     1      20      AA      21
2     2      10      BB      8
3     3      20      CC      NaN
4     1      30      AA      31
5     2      10      BB      8
```

I've tried:

```
df['col4'][df['col3']=='AA'] = df['col2'] + df['col1']
df['col4'][df['col3']=='AA'] = df['col2'] + df['col1']
```

And naturally I get a SettingWithCopyWarning

**What is the proper way to achieve this without the warning?** I've tried apply and set_value, but I can't seem to pass so many df references into the params.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use nested [np.where()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
In [5]: df['col4'] = np.where(df.col3 == 'AA',
                              df.col2 + df.col1,
                              np.where(df.col3 == 'BB',
                                       df.col2 - df.col1,
                                       np.nan))

In [6]: df
Out[6]:
   col1  col2 col3  col4
1     1    20   AA  21.0
2     2    10   BB   8.0
3     3    20   CC   NaN
4     1    30   AA  31.0
5     2    10   BB   8.0
```

Comment: @Yeile, you are welcome. That's a common pattern for such tasks

Answer (score 1):

An uncommon pattern :-)

```
a = ((df.col3.values[:, None] == ['AA', 'BB']) * [1, -1]).sum(1, keepdims=True)
b = np.hstack([np.ones_like(a), np.where(a == 0, np.nan, a)])
df.assign(col4=df[['col1', 'col2']].mul(b).sum(1, skipna=False))

   col1  col2 col3  col4
1     1    20   AA  21.0
2     2    10   BB  -8.0
3     3    20   CC   NaN
4     1    30   AA  31.0
5     2    10   BB  -8.0
```

Comment: It's a very creative solution! ;)

Comment: @piRSquared that hacking!